# Is it necessary for a Push down Automaton (PDA) to have a stack?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I am given a Finite Automaton and the question is to design an Equivalent PDA for it. This is my FA:
[image: FA]

Is this PDA correct or do I need to add a stack to it? If its right when is the stack needed?
[image: PDA]

Comment: I don't really understand the picture to say if it's correct, but yes, for regular languages you don't need a stack. Stack gives PDA power to recognize languages which FA can't. So it's natural that you don't need this power for regular languages.

Comment: By "don't need" I mean that PDA won't use it. Of course, to match PDA definition, you still have to write some trivial rules for stack manipulation: in the beginning put a certain symbol (say, S) on the stack, and for each transition simply replace S with S.

Comment: This is my confusion. If in exams the question is to draw a PDA for an FA do I have to draw a PDA with all the push, pop symbols or I can just draw it with read, start and accept symbols. I got it that we don't need a stack but on paper how will we draw such PDA?

Comment: We can't answer your question; your instructor would be the one to ask.

Comment: For those who are as confused as I was by the diagrams in this question: (1) [DFA +/- notation](https://ycpcs.github.io/cs340-fall2016/lectures/lecture02.html); (2) [read/push/pop PDA notation](http://bummerang.tripod.com/lectures/CT313/topic5.html). The PDA notation I'm familiar with is completely different (basically the JFLAP-style DFA notation but with more stuff written on each transition edge).